# timing problem with laser scan (synchronizing with odometry)

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, timestamp, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I've got a timing problem with my laser scans. I receive laser scan data through a tcp socket (it's simulated laser data from another system in the network). While the robot is standing still everything is fine. But as soon as it moves/turns, the laser scan gets biased depending on how fast the robot is moving/turning. It looks like the scans are stamped wrong in relation to odometry/tf.

At the moment I stamp all my sensor data with the time stamp of the moment they arrive in the node. I suppose there is some kind of offset due to the time some of my data needs to get through ROS.

So, how can I synchronize my nodes to get rid of the speed depending bias?

Thank you!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93041/timing-problem-with-laser-scan-(synchronizing-with-odometry)/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From our experience the recommend way to syncronize machines is using the chrony ntp client. There's a few notes here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

If you are running on a system that does cannot be syncronized or you are going to be using system time @skiesel's answer would be the way to go.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-10-22**:
I see and I agree - synchronizing both systems would be a great help. Is it possible to synchronize a Linux and a Windows system like this? My simulator runs on a Windows machine.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-22**:
Yeah, it's just using NTP, there should be plenty of windows clients.  And it's probably builtin too.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-10-22**:
Alright, I'll give it a try. Thanks a lot!